# React setting state not working when i create form fields dynamically

Tags: reactjs, state

i originally hard coded a form which worked fine when i had very similar code but now that i have decided to make my React form dynamic the fields don't update any more.

Its probably just something i'm not understanding about how state works. The state appears to set, but on re-render the firstName goes back to the original value

this is a simplified version i'm just trying to update firstName with

```
class Test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        usrForm: null
    };

    this.formFields = {
        fistName: {
            value: this.state.firstName,
            type: 'text'
        },
        lastName: {
            value: this.state.lastName,
            type: 'text'
        }
    };
}
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.buildForm();
};

updateField = e => {
    this.setState({
        firstName: e.target.value
    });
    this.buildForm();
};

buildForm() {
    const usrForm = Object.keys(this.formFields).map(field => {
        switch (this.formFields[field].type) {
            case 'text':
                return ( <
                    input type = {
                        this.formFields[field].type
                    }
                    value = {
                        this.formFields[field].value
                    }
                    onChange = {
                        this.updateField
                    }
                    />
                );
                // case 'button':
                //     return <button onclick={.....} />
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
    this.setState({
        usrForm: usrForm
    });
}

render() {
    return <div > {
        this.state.usrForm
    } < /div>;
}
```

}

any Ideas??

Thanks

Comment: value set to `firstName` but read (value=) from `this.formFields...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several points that you should address. For example, you have a typo on this.formFields (it says fistName and not firstName). Also, you set this.formFields in the constructor, using the state values. That will be called only once, so your values won't be updated. You need to updated them manually.
Also a note. The setState method is async, so if you want to use the state values right after setting them, you can use them in a callback.

Can you try this?

```
class Test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        usrForm: null
    };

    this.formFields = {
        firstName: {
            value: this.state.firstName,
            type: 'text'
        },
        lastName: {
            value: this.state.lastName,
            type: 'text'
        }
    };
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.buildForm();
};

updateField = e => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }, () => this.buildForm());

};

buildForm() {
    const usrForm = Object.keys(this.formFields).map(field => {
        this.formFields[field].value = this.state[field];
        switch (this.formFields[field].type) {
            case 'text':
                return (<
                        input type={
                        this.formFields[field].type
                    }
                              value={
                                  this.formFields[field].value
                              }
                              onChange={
                                  this.updateField
                              }
                              name={field}
                    />
                );
            // case 'button':
            //     return <button onclick={.....} />
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
    this.setState({
        usrForm: usrForm
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div> {
            this.state.usrForm
        } </div>

    )

}
}
```

Comment: Hey... thanks for that, worked a charm... the update function change + this.formFields[field].value = this.state[field]; in buildForm i think did the job nicely...cheers!!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this happening because the state is not being set incorrectly. In your update field function, you are setting value against firstName which is not where you are reading it from.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        usrForm: null,
        formField: {
            fistName: {
                value: 'Fred',
                type: 'text'
            },
            lastName: {
                value: 'Smith',
                type: 'text'
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Change your update field to update state according to the field which was not happening earlier. Also, I have moved buildForm to setState callback since it is async.

```
updateField = (e, field) => {
    const newFormFields = {...this.state.formField};
    newFormFields[field] = { value: e.target.value, type: 'text'}
    this.setState({
        formField: newFormField 
    }, () => {this.buildForm()});
};
```

Also, update your onChange to call updateField like following

```
onChange = {(e) => {this.updateField(e, field)}}
```

(Note: I think you are nesting state too much which is not recommended. Think of simplifying your logic.)

Comment: Hey... i tried your method but I had a few issues and the state wasn't updating properly for me... thanks for your help though, gave me another approach to think about